# What the difference in using async NSURLConnection from a static method with an object as delegate, and calling it IN an object with self as delegate?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsurlconnection

When i try to send – initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: message to NSURLConnection from a class method, passing an ad-hoc delegate object, delegate methods never gets called.
When, instead, – initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: is sent by an object, and the delegate of NSURLConnection is self, than all goes OK.
Someone can explain me why?
i stucked here for three days or so ^^'

Comment: what exactly is an ad-hoc delegate object ?

Comment: Can you post the code that is having the problem? Perhaps you're not retaining the "ad-hoc delegate" anywhere, but it's impossible for us to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: the code is a bit complex.. and i'm thinking if refactor it or not, to have methods only as instance methods.. 
This is more a deep curiosity, that a real unbypassable problem.
But i'd like to be good with cocoa.. so..

@Michal: i meant an object crafted at the sole purpose to be a delegate for NSURLConnection.

@GregInYEG: the delegate is, in facts, released nowhere :p and it is [[ alloc] init] ^_^

The only difference between the two cases, is that in the first, the method is called from a static context (that is: a class method), and in the second.. it is called by an instance method.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference. If your delegate methods aren't getting called it is because your implementation is obviously incorrect. The target delegate must be in the same runloop, and if you're releasing autoreleased objects or something like that, your implementation is wrong.

Post your code or recheck your work.

Comment: when NSURLConnection is used by the static method, the control returns to the calling method, without any delegate method being called (checked with breakpoints too).
nothing is autoreleased nor released, given that NSURLConnection is instantiated using initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:

the app is not multithreaded.